# Any way to get possible messages according to the sha512 hash signature?

Tags: hash, sha512

I have hash (signature) of a message. I know that a message is always a hex number with 64 digits. Is there a way how to get the set of possible 64 digits messages? Or is there a way how to get any assumptions/features about the message according to the signature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No

If SHA-512 is a secure hash function, which it is generally believed to be, then knowing the hash value provides no useful information about the input.  In particular, no method for guessing the possible input(s) will be significantly more efficient than just brute-force guessing all possible inputs, which will take an average of 2^255 tries; far more than you can possibly hope to do, unless you have other independent knowledge about the message that drastically reduces the number of possibilities.

This property of secure hash functions is key to modern cryptography.  If you were hoping to use this to recover passwords from a hash or something like that, think again.